# How to create a macro from an existing macro?

Tags: excel

I am writing code in Workbook A to create and run a macro in Workbook B. I know how to call and run a macro from another workbook, but cannot figure how I can create a new macro. All I need is to create Macro1 and select to Edit it and I will have the code ready elsewhere to copy and paste in and run the new macro. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: So there may be another solution. It looks to me like the issue you're trying to solve is VBA macro portability. Excel supports a "personal" workbook that can operate on and is accessible by any workbook. If you add the macro you want to use in workbook B to your personal one you won't have to worry about duplicating the macro per workbook. If I have misunderstood your issue, ignore this comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unless I am also misunderstanding you, I don't think this will work for me. I am creating this tool to distribute out to my broader team and the code needs to be able to run on everyone's individual device, not just mine. This won't work if I create the macros in my personal workbook, right?

Comment: Ah that was not the use case I thought you needed. You're right, it will not work if the personal  workbook is not on each device. I suppose you may be able to set the folder excel loads the workbook from to be a network drive and host the workbook there, but I have never tried that and it may be more work than an alternative. Best of luck in finding a solution!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already? Please [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I haven't really tried anything... I typically search my questions on here in an attempt to get started, but no questions previously posted match what I am looking to do.